# Get row with highest or lowest value from a GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm trying to get the row with the highest/lowest number, after performing a `GROUP BY`:

Here is my test data

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+----+-------+------+
| id | value | name |
+----+-------+------+
|  1 |    10 | row1 |
|  2 |    12 | row2 |
|  3 |    10 | row2 |
|  4 |     5 | row2 |
+----+-------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

To get the lowest value, I'll use `MIN()`

```
mysql> SELECT id, name, MIN(value) AS value FROM test GROUP BY name;
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | value |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | row1 |    10 |
|  2 | row2 |     5 |
+----+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, the id `row2` is `2`, but it should be `4`.

I also tried with a join:

```
mysql> SELECT t1.* FROM 
       (SELECT id, name, MIN(value) AS value 
          FROM test GROUP BY name) AS t1 
       INNER JOIN test AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | value |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | row1 |    10 |
|  2 | row2 |     5 |
+----+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

How can I get the correct ID for each result based on what the lowest `value` is?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
SELECT t.* FROM test t
JOIN 
( SELECT Name, MIN(Value) minVal
  FROM test GROUP BY Name
) t2
ON t.Value = t2.minVal AND t.Name = t2.Name;
```

Output:

| ID | VALUE | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | row1 |
| 4 | 5 | row2 |

See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/149d6a/1)

- [Demo with more values](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13bed/1)
- [Demo with duplicate values](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0f24/1)
- [Demo with removing duplicate values (using `DISTINCT`)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0f24/2)

Here I have self-joined the table with minVal and Name.

Comment: That seems to work, can you mention why the subquery won't return the id, so that I can do? `SELECT t.* FROM test t
JOIN 
( SELECT id, Name, MIN(Value) minVal
  FROM test GROUP BY Name
) t2
ON t.id = t2.id;`

Comment: @PabloFernandezheelhook - When we select values using functions then the other values are taken randomly. E.g. here it will select ID randomly. So don't select ID from inner query. So instead of self-joining by `ID` join it with `values` and `name` field.

Comment: Are these fiddles out of date? or is there something you need to do in order to run them, I always just get a screen saying loading.. and build schema, but pressing those buttons does nothing?

Comment: @Paul501: This must be the latest reply I have ever given. SQLFiddle seems to update the database versions to the latest one and discontinue using the old one. Hence, fiddles created using the old one don't execute successfully. I have updated the db for all fiddles in this answer.

Comment: @hims056 The distinct does not delete a single duplicate for me? The result has more rows then a distinct on "name" without the join. Why is that? (mysql)

Comment: @veritaS Any possibility of those duplicate rows having different values in any specific column? Better if you could show your table + query in SQLFiddle.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1eaee8/1/0 I am guessing cause the "value" (deliverer price in my case) is the same

Comment: @veritaS are you expecting one record instead of two where GGARTNUM='0315442'?

Comment: @hims056 yes, currently checking how I can achieve this

Comment: @veritaS Using `DISTINCT` won't work as it checks for whole row to be distinct. You need to specify only fields which are actually distinct. Like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f218c/2