# #1054 - Unknown column 'val' in 'on clause' when selecting MIN()

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT IF(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t1.dal, NOW())) < 0,
          -TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t1.dal, NOW())),
          NULL
       ) AS val, t2.*
FROM test t1
JOIN 
  (SELECT prod, MIN(
                    IF(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(dal, NOW())) < 0,
                       -TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(dal, NOW())),
                       NULL
                    )
                 ) AS minVal
   FROM test
   GROUP BY prod
  ) t2
ON val = minVal
AND t1.prodotto = t2.prodotto;
```

This query returns #1054 - Unknown column 'val' in 'on clause'.

What I want to do is to select the MIN() as describled but also the corrisponding `id`.

I want to obtain the same result as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910050/get-row-with-highest-or-lowest-value-from-a-group-by) question, but instead of simpy selecting `MIN(Value) minVal` and then compare with `ON t.Value = t2.minVal AND t.prod = t2.prod` I add the operation MIN(IF(TIME...)`so I have no idea how to compare then on the`ON` clause, which returns error with my try.

Comment: What if you explain the real task you're solving?

Comment: it doesn't explain the original task. It says that you want to do the same as in another question but using wrong syntax. If **it is** the question - then, no, you cannot execute syntactically incorrect queries.

Comment: `ON IF(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t1.dal, NOW())) < 0,
          -TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t1.dal, NOW())),
          NULL
       ) = minVal`

Comment: Virtual fields are not available in all parts of MySQL queries. I know this is going to be an ugly solution, but copy and paste the if statement you are defining `val` with and replace the `val` on the `ON` clause with it, should sort it.