# MySQL avoid repeating values

Tags: mysql, select, join

I am using the query below to list orders that contain 4 or more case SKUs. Once those orders are located I do not want to repeat customer_email.

Current output example:

```
Order ID    | customer_email    | total_cases_invoiced
5           | this@that.com     | 6
45          | email1@here.com   | 4
32          | email1@here.com   | 7
23          | email1@here.com   | 5
28          | another@email.com | 10
```

**Desired output** example:

```
Order ID    | customer_email    | total_cases_invoiced
5           | this@that.com     | 6
45          | email1@here.com   | 4
28          | another@email.com | 10
```

Current Query:

```
SELECT 
    *, customer_email, SUM(qty_invoiced) AS total_cases_invoiced
FROM
    mg_sales_flat_order_item
        JOIN
    mg_sales_flat_order ON mg_sales_flat_order.entity_id = mg_sales_flat_order_item.order_id
WHERE
    (mg_sales_flat_order_item.sku LIKE '%A'
        OR mg_sales_flat_order_item.sku LIKE '%F'
        OR mg_sales_flat_order_item.sku LIKE '%B'
        OR mg_sales_flat_order_item.sku LIKE '%C'
        OR mg_sales_flat_order_item.sku LIKE '%FP'
        OR mg_sales_flat_order_item.sku LIKE '%AP')
        AND row_total != 0
GROUP BY order_id
HAVING SUM(qty_invoiced) >= 4
ORDER BY customer_email DESC
```

Comment: Do you case which `Order ID` and `total_cases_invoiced` values are shown in the result set? Your "desired" output doesn't seem to indicate you care, in which case I would suggest just having the email address in your select.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get row with highest or lowest value from a GROUP BY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910050/get-row-with-highest-or-lowest-value-from-a-group-by)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to group your `customer_email` like this along with `customer_id`?

```
SELECT 
    *, customer_email, SUM(qty_invoiced) AS total_cases_invoiced
FROM
    mg_sales_flat_order_item
        JOIN
    mg_sales_flat_order ON mg_sales_flat_order.entity_id = mg_sales_flat_order_item.order_id
WHERE
    (mg_sales_flat_order_item.sku LIKE '%A'
        OR mg_sales_flat_order_item.sku LIKE '%F'
        OR mg_sales_flat_order_item.sku LIKE '%B'
        OR mg_sales_flat_order_item.sku LIKE '%C'
        OR mg_sales_flat_order_item.sku LIKE '%FP'
        OR mg_sales_flat_order_item.sku LIKE '%AP')
        AND row_total != 0
GROUP BY (order_id,customer_email)
HAVING SUM(qty_invoiced) >= 4
ORDER BY customer_email DESC
```